# Melt a big data frame without pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dask, melt

I have a 3GB dataset with 40k rows and 60k columns which Pandas is unable to read and I would like to melt the file based on the current index.

The current file looks like this:

[image]

The first column is an index and I would like to melt all the file based on this index.
I tried pandas and dask, but all of them crush when reading the big file.

Do you have any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: `dask` has a built-in `melt` function that does exactly what `pandas` has implemented.

Comment: @Fourier It's specifically stating that both pandas and dask crash when reading the file

Comment: @ChatterOne This skipped my attention. Then more details are needed, is the `dtype` specified when reading in? Do you use chunking to process the data in chunks?

Comment: When I load it with dask I get the following error: Sample is not large enough to include at least one row of data. Please increase the number of bytes in `sample` in the call to `read_csv`/`read_table`   AND when I load it in chunks it crush when I melt the file

Comment: @AliciaPliego what do you use as `sample` parameter for `dd.read_table` ?

Comment: I used sample= 100 and also 1000, 100000 and 1000000

Comment: @AliciaPliego `sample` is defined in bytes. With 60K+ columns try 4e6 to be on the safe side. And I suppose your data is all `int`? Try to set this parameter when reading as well.

Comment: How do you deal with the partitions created?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206452/discussion-between-fourier-and-alicia-pliego).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `chunksize` property of pandas. See for example [How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25962187/6734876).

You will process N rows at one time, without loading the whole dataframe. `N` will depend on your computer: if N is low, it will cost less memory but it will increase the run time and will cost more IO load.

```py
# create an object reading your file 100 rows at a time
reader = pd.read_csv( 'bigfile.tsv', sep='\t', header=None, chunksize=100 )
# process each chunk at a time
for chunk in file:
    result = chunk.melt()
    # export the results into a new file
    result.to_csv( 'bigfile_melted.tsv', header=None, sep='\t', mode='a' )
```

Furthermore, you can use the argument `dtype=np.int32` for `read_csv` if you have integer or `dtype=np.float32` to process data faster if you do not need precision.

NB: here you have examples of memory usage: [Using Chunksize in Pandas](http://acepor.github.io/2017/08/03/using-chunksize/).